# How to get selected data using onChange event using jQuery Data table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on jQuery Data table to load few data from mysql database.

**Here is the html code :**

```
<table id="employee-grid"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>User Id</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Package Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**jQuery code for jQuery Data Table and My Ajax Request :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax":{
            url :"server_processing.php", // json datasource
            type: "post",  // method  , by default get
            error: function(){  // error handling
                $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
                $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");

            }
        }
    } );

    $("#employee-grid").on('change', function() {
        var status = $('.changeStatus').val();
        alert(status);
        $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo SITE_URL . 'toplevel/update-data'; ?>",
            data : {
                'statusChange' : status
            }, 
            type : 'POST',
        });
    });

});
```

but When I select the option then every time it's passing **first option value**

For e.g. This `selected` option tag has these value :

```
<option value='1|11' $statusMsg1>Active</option>
<option value='2|11' $statusMsg2>Blocked</option>
```

It's always passing `1|11` value !! It's should be pass my selected option value. I don't understand why it's happening :(

Answer (score 1):

Change **this**:

```
$(".changeStatus").on("change", function(){
    var status = $('.changeStatus').val();
    alert(status);

    // e.t.c...
});
```

To **this**:

```
$(".changeStatus option").change(function(){
    var status = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?= SITE_URL . 'toplevel/update-data'; ?>",
        method: "POST",
        data: { statusChange : status }, 
        success: function(data){
            alert(status);
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ah.. Using it's not calling `Ajax` :(

Comment: @shibbirahmed I don't see a reason why it wouldn't.. any errors in the console?

Comment: @shibbirahmed please tell me you didn't just do `// e.t.c...`, instead of your actual **Ajax**?

Comment: Yes I checked it with alert but not alert message.

Comment: @shibbirahmed how does it go now??

Comment: Not working yet. I need to first select the `#employee-grid` id. Then showing me the alert message. Without `#employee-grid` it's doing anything

Comment: `onChange` event is only calling if I use only `#employee-grid`